# Example code given for curve fitting with Gnu Scientific Library wont run.

Tags: c, curve-fitting, gsl, dyld

I am trying to use GSL for least square fitting, but I can't even make the [example](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/%20%22example%22Example-programs-for-Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html) run properly. It compiles, but when running the program it gives the error

> `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _cblas_dnrm2`
>
> `Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgsl.0.dylib`
>
> `Expected in: dynamic lookup`

I believe I have narrowed down the problem to the line

> `gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_set (s, &f, &x.vector);`

but I have not the slightest clue why.

I am running it on OSX with GSL 1.15 (though I innitially insalled the wrong version, 1.9). I compile it in the terminal using: `gcc unchanged_example.c -o examplefitter -lgsl -lm`

EDIT: solution was found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=420638). adding '`-lgslcblas`' when compiling sorted it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the shared library that contains `_cblas_dnrm2` and link it into your application.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So where do I find that library. Just searching finder, it seems it doesn't exsist? This is probably very basic, but when I do find it, how exacrly would I link it? excuse my ignorance, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I would guess that it's part of your GSL download, but you haven't set your library link path properly.  It's been too long since I last did C programming to remember, but I think it has to do with the -lm path that you set.

Comment: hm. I think I may be a little out of my depth here. To be honest, I don't really know what the '-lm' means, I just added it because I saw a reccomendation to do so somewhere. the same thing happenes with or without it though. What should I expect '_cblas_dnrm2' to be? Should there be a file named so somewhere? I have gotten other gsl functions to work compiling this way, any idea why this particular library would not link properly?

Comment: Better dig in and figure it out.  It's been too long for me to give you much actionable advice.  But your application requires a number of libraries to be linked in.  It's your job to find them and tell your app how to link them in.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this you need to link against two libraries...

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -g -lgslcblas -lgsl -std=c11 -pedantic-errors
```